# How to make iCal notifications on the Mac more noticeable?

Tags: notifications, calendar, ical

I often work with an extra monitor plugged into my MacBook Pro. Because iCal alerts for appointments on my primary screen only, I often miss appointments (especially if the sound volume is low). This happens because the notification is not very prominent, but shows on the corner of a screen I'm often not looking at.

So, my question is this. Are there any ways to make the calendar notifications in iCal more "disruptive?" Apple's screen flicker (in the accessibility menu) for alerts would do it, but it does not seem to work with the calendar notifications. Another possibility would be to have the iCal alerts override the volume settings. Any suggestions on how to do either of those things? Or any other suggestion that would help make the calendar notification more noticeable? Perhaps increase the size of the tiny notification box? Help would be appreciated.